# Page background colour and button issue - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

New to react native and trying to style a page I have added a table on. I want to change the background colour of the page but can not seem to figure it out if anyone can give me a hand and also on the table I have a button but its slightly to the left (see screenshot) I've tried using different positional options but nothing changes, how can I centre the button within the cell?

Thanks

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Cell } from "react-native-table-component";

export default class ExampleFour extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ["Head", "Head2", "Head3", "Head4"],
      tableData: [
        ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
      ]
    };
  }

  _alertIndex(index) {
    Alert.alert(`This is row ${index + 1}`);
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const element = (data, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(index)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: "#fff" },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: "#808B97" },
  text: { margin: 6 },
  row: { flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: "white" },
  btn: {
    width: 58,
    height: 18,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 2
  },
  btnText: { textAlign: "center", color: "#fff" }
});
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Friend I am for your help
Look at this expo https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/stackover

Answer (score 1):

to change backgroundColor

```
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: "red" },// to change backgroundColor
```

center tha button

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}//add style to this component
in style 
 btn: {
    width: 58,
    height: 18,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 2,
    alignSelf:'center'
  },
```

you can see in this [expo](https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/stackover)

Comment: ah, thank you so much I used everything but alignSelf. One last question is there an easy way to allow the table to rotate when the phone is turned or will it require a lot of code to do so?

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color you can replace the container `backgroundColor` which is currently `"#fff"` to the color you want and add `alignSelf` to `center` for button
See code below:

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Cell } from "react-native-table-component";

export default class ExampleFour extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ["Head", "Head2", "Head3", "Head4"],
      tableData: [
        ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
      ]
    };
  }

  _alertIndex(index) {
    Alert.alert(`This is row ${index + 1}`);
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const element = (data, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => this._alertIndex(index)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1 }}>
          <Row
            data={state.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.text}
          />
          {state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
            <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
              {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                <Cell
                  key={cellIndex}
                  data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </TableWrapper>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: "blue" },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: "#808B97" },
  text: { margin: 6 },
  row: { flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: "white" },
  btn: {
    width: 58,
    height: 18,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 2,
    alignSelf:'center'
  },
  btnText: { textAlign: "center", color: "#fff" }
});
```

And for portrait and landscape mode, it should automatically change that if its in flex. Try that and hope it helps. feel free for doubts